# Filter criteria based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to filter a range based on a cell value:

It works:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table").Range("$A$38:$O$68").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("LATAM", "NOAM"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Doesn't work:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table").Range("$A$38:$O$68").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table").Range("Q100").Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Q100 = "LATAM", "NOAM"
```

What is the desired input for criteria?

Comment: Is `"LATAM", "NOAM"` the exact value in `Q100` ?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried without quotes and with double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an array if you want to apply more that one value.

```
dim crit() as string
crit = split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table").Range("Q100").Value, ",")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table").Range("$A$38:$O$68").AutoFilter Field:=2 Criteria1:=crit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

N.B. If your cell Q100 contains quotes, you have to get rid of it:

```
 crit = split(replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table").Range("Q100").Value, """",""), ",")
```

Comment: Why don't you update your answer to show removing the double quotes - this would make it a correct answer

Comment: @ Robin Mackenzie: Because usually there aren't quotes in a cell , see Erikas comment

Answer (score 1):

You can put `LATAM` in Q100 am `NOAM` in Q101 (both without quotation marks) and use `Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table").Range("Q100:Q101").Value` as criteria.